# How can I insert image and text into a Microsoft Word template?

Tags: c#, spire.doc

Below code with spire.doc

```
var doc = new Document();
doc.LoadFromFile(@"E:\test.docx", FileFormat.Doc);
var image = Image.FromFile(@"E:\nice.jpg");
var picture1 = doc.Sections[0].Paragraphs[0].AppendPicture(image);
picture1.VerticalAlignment = ShapeVerticalAlignment.Top;
picture1.HorizontalAlignment = ShapeHorizontalAlignment.Left;
picture1.TextWrappingStyle = TextWrappingStyle.Square;
doc.SaveToFile(@"..\..\result.doc", FileFormat.Doc);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"..\..\result.doc");
```

How can I insert image and text into certain positions in a Word template using either the `spire.doc` or the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` libraries?

Or similar this [link](http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/word-automation-in-c/#comment-74219) with insert image to certain position in world template.

Answer (score 0):

- [add images after the last image/text in a word document using interop C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414973/add-images-after-the-last-image-text-in-a-word-document-using-interop-c-sharp)
- [How to change the size of a picture after inserting it into a word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483471/how-to-change-the-size-of-a-picture-after-inserting-it-into-a-word-document)
- [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=InlineShapes.AddPicture)

Answer (score 0):

using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word,

first, you need to ensure the selection is in right position,

then,
insert images, there are couple of options, here is my code,

```
If bInline Then
    Dim oInlineShape As InlineShape = m_oWordApp.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=sImageFilePath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
oInlineShape.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = nAlignment
    If nHeight > 0 AndAlso nWidth > 0 Then
        oInlineShape.LockAspectRatio = MsoTriState.msoFalse
        oInlineShape.Height = nHeight
        oInlineShape.Width = nWidth
    End If
Else
    Dim oShape As Word.Shape = m_oWordApp.ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(Anchor:=m_oWordApp.Selection.Range, FileName:=sImageFilePath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
    If nHeight > 0 AndAlso nWidth > 0 Then
        oShape.LockAspectRatio = MsoTriState.msoFalse
        oShape.Height = nHeight
        oShape.Width = nWidth
    End If
End If
```

insert text is quite easy, you just need to ensure selection object is in right position, then,

```
m_oWordApp.Selection.Text = sMsg
'you can update background colors ....
m_oWordApp.Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = 0
'you update fonts ....
m_oWordApp.Selection.Font.Bold = True
```

Hope it helps.